# Не работает кнопка внутри Custom view

Tags: android, button, виджет, customview, компоненты

Привет. Мне нужно создать свой компонент, который будет наследоватся от RelativeLayout. Для описания стилей его елементов хочу использовать layout xml. 
Если я создаю кнопку програмно и добавляю ее к кастомному компоненту, то она работает отлично:
 - я могу получить доступ к кнопке и програмно изменить текст, или цвет
 - сделать обработчик

```
 public void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.native_ad, this);
    this.adWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.nativeAdWebView);
    this.adTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nativeAdTitle);
    //this.adButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nativeAdButton);  не работает
    this.adButton = new Button(context);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    this.addView(adButton, params);
    adWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    adWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    adWebView.buildDrawingCache();
    adWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    adWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
}
```

Как мне сделать так чтобы оно видило кнопку с xml файла. С TextView все работает отлично.

```
public class CustomComponent extends RelativeLayout {

WebView adWebView;
TextView adTitle;
Button adButton;
Context context;

public CustomComponent (Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init(context);
}

public CustomComponent (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init(context);
}

public CustomComponent (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    init(context);
}
```

в самом хмл файле прописаны все елементы, но нормально видит и работает только TextView. Аналогичная проблема с WebView, но думаю что у них одно решение.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/nativeAdTitle"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nativeAdWebView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nativeAdTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

</WebView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nativeAdButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: То что есть сейчас]

Comment: Проблема не ясна. У вас кнопку не видно? И покажите разметку. Может у вас id неправильный?

Comment: кнопка отображается (серая на картинке), но она не реагирурет на методы (setText, setBackgroundColor, ...) синяя кнопка создана програмно и с ней методы работают.

Comment: Вы описываете невозможную ситуацию) Попробуйте InstantRun в настройках студии отключить.

Comment: кнопка отображается только поточу что я делаю inflate(getContext(), R.layout.native_ad, this); но больше с ней я ничего не могу сделать. она получается только для декора.

p.s.  попробуйте добавить код в проект и сами увидите, что она есть но не реагирует на обращения к ней